# Pandas moving average using a standard deviation in Python

Tags: python, pandas, random-forest, moving-average, standard-deviation

I want to smooth a noise using a `moving average filter` after fitting a regression model using a `RandomForestRegressor` for a data set I am considering using found in [this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Iv8dfU4fTUdlE0VUJKUnctSkE)

```
import pandas as pd
import math
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor, GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_squared_error, make_scorer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split


n_features=3000

df = pd.read_csv('cubic32.csv')

for i in range(1,n_features):
    df['X_t'+str(i)] = df['X'].shift(i)

print(df)

df.dropna(inplace=True)


X = df.drop('Y', axis=1)
y = df['Y']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.40)

X_train = X_train.drop('time', axis=1)
X_test = X_test.drop('time', axis=1)


parameters = {'n_estimators': [10]}
clf_rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1)
clf = GridSearchCV(clf_rf, parameters, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', n_jobs=-1)
model = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
model.cv_results_['params'][model.best_index_]
math.sqrt(model.best_score_*-1)
model.grid_scores_

#####
print()
print(model.grid_scores_)
print("The best score: ",model.best_score_)

print("RMSE:",math.sqrt(model.best_score_*-1))

clf_rf.fit(X_train,y_train)
modelPrediction = clf_rf.predict(X_test)
print(modelPrediction)

print("Number of predictions:",len(modelPrediction))

meanSquaredError=mean_squared_error(y_test, modelPrediction)
print("Mean Square Error (MSE):", meanSquaredError)
rootMeanSquaredError = sqrt(meanSquaredError)
print("Root-Mean-Square Error (RMSE):", rootMeanSquaredError)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
index_values=range(0,len(y_test))

y_test.sort_index(inplace=True)
X_test.sort_index(inplace=True)

modelPred_test = clf_rf.predict(X_test)
ax.plot(pd.Series(index_values), y_test.values)

smoothed=pd.rolling_mean(modelPred_test, 90, min_periods=90, freq=None, center=False, how=None)
PlotInOne=pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([pd.Series(smoothed), pd.Series(y_test.values)], axis=1))
plt.figure(); PlotInOne.plot(); plt.legend(loc='best')
```

However, the plot of the predicted values seems (as shown below) to be very coarse (the blue line).

The orange line is a plot of the actual value.

[image]

How can we calculate the **standard deviation** of the prediction (blue line) in the plot shown above and pass it as an interval parameter to the moving average that the window runs on? Currently, I am setting the size of the moving window manually as 50 but I wanted to pass the value of the standard deviation instead.

```
smoothed=pd.rolling_mean(modelPred_test, 50, min_periods=50, freq=None, center=False, how=None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pd.rolling_mean(modelPred_test,windows=round(np.std(modelPred_test)))
```

You can plug the standard deviation into the minimum window as well~

Answer (score 0):

```
smoothed=pd.rolling(modelPred_test, 50, min_periods=50, freq=None, center=False, how=None).std()
```